# XMPP resolved names from roster

Tags: php, xml, xmpp, rosters

How can I resolve the names from roster list? The request I'm sending (using my [XMPP-PHP lib](https://packagist.org/packages/norgul/xmpp-php)) to get the roster looks like this:

```
<iq type="get">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"></query>
</iq>
```

But only thing I get here are unresolved names. Response from server (which is not in my control, but acts as a proxy to FB, Viber etc) comes in this format:

```
<iq type="result" to="xxx">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
        <item jid="xxx@fb.xxx" ask="subscribe" subscription="from">
            <group>test</group>
        </item>
    </query>
</iq>
```

Is there some special way I can ask the server to provide me the resolved name from JID?